# Will hash_equals ever return true for two different strings?

Tags: php, hash

Is there any situation where two different strings passed into `hash_equals()` would return true? Are "hash collisions" an issue with hash_equals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`hash_equals`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) just appears to be poorly named. It strictly does a string comparison and does not involve hashing (thus no possibility of hash collisions).

I believe the name comes from a common use case for a timing-attack safe string comparison function, which is to compare two strings representing hashes.